# How to stream video frames in C#

Tags: c#, .net, video-streaming, webcam, bitmapimage

I have got some event where I am getting bitmap of webcam.

How do I can stream it to some local port in a simplest way?

```
using WpfMultimedia;
using WpfMultimedia.Webcam;

var _webCam = new VideoCapture(DeviceManager.GetVideoInputDevices().First(), null);
_webCam.CaptureFrame += OnFrameCaptured;
_webCam.Start();

...

private void OnFrameCaptured(object sender, CaptureFrameEventArgs e)
{
    //latest BitmapImage from camera is in e.Frame
    BitmapImage _currentFrame = e.Frame
    .... Stream it to http://localhost:9797 ?
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can start by converting the `BitmapImage` to a "stremeable" type of data.

```
byte[] Data;
JpegBitmapEncoder Encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapImage));
using(MemoryStream MemStream = new MemoryStream())
{
Encoder.Save(ms);
Data = MemStream.ToArray();
}
```

Maybe you can use a different encoder for performance.

Then you should use UDP (TCP if the data is small enough, and speed is not a requirement) to send this frames and decode them, there you can create a video.

But probably there are some libraries already created for video streaming and you don't have to code that yourself.